# Python: None type object is not callable

Tags: python, pygame

I'm doing a game in pygame and what I'm trying to do, is to make an entity target another. 
When I call the target function, I get "TypeError: NoneType object is not callable" What I understood after doing research on this error, is that it occurs, when you try to use the return value of a function that hasn't any.
But, my function isn't supposed to return something and I don't use a return value, so I'm a bit out of ideas.
I hope someone can help me, here is my code:
target function

```
def target(self,x,y):
    target = self.world.getPointEntity(x,y)  
    if target != None and target.get_itarget():
        self.set_target(target)
```

call to target function

```
self.player.target(x,y)
```

If you have any questions, feel free to ask.

EDIT: Code of getPointEntity function:

```
    def getPointEntity(self, x, y, searchRange=24):
        for entity in self.entities.itervalues():
            if entity != None:
                distance = entity.get_distance(x, y)
                if distance < searchRange:
                    return entity
        return None
```

As for the get_itarget function, it just returns True or False depending on the respective entity being a legal target or not.
The traceback points to line with self.player.target()
Full traceback:

```
__Main2.py", line 971, in <module>
Game(1920,1080)    
__Main2.py", line 795, in __init__
self.run()
__Main2.py", line 910, in run
self.player.target(x,y)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

EDIT: the method target belongs to the super class of the player class.

```
class Player(LivingEntity):
    def __init__(self, name, world, image, x, y, speedModifier, sizeradius, inv_image, filler, shadow, scx, scy, animseq, animn):
        LivingEntity.__init__(self, name, world, image, x, y, speedModifier, sizeradius, animseq, animn)
        self.inventory = None
        self.scx = scx
        self.scy = scy
        self.addInventory(inv_image, filler, shadow)

class LivingEntity(GameEntity):
    def __init__(self, name, world, images, x, y, speedModifier, sizeradius, animseq, animn, xshift=48, yshift=48):
        GameEntity.__init__(self, name, world, images, x, y, speedModifier, sizeradius, animseq, animn, xshift, yshift)
        self.target = None

    def set_target(self, target):
        self.target = target

    def target(self,x,y):
        target = self.world.getPointEntity(x,y)  
        if target != None and target.get_itarget():
            self.set_target(target)
```

I kind of solved the problem by putting the check for a target entity outside of the target function. I can't really see the differnce but it seems to work.

Comment: I edited your code's indentation.  Please double check that it's right.

Comment: Include full error in your question.

Comment: please state the exact line, where the error occurs

Comment: FWIW, using `target` as the name of a local variable as well as a method name is legal Python, but it's confusing to people reading your code.

Comment: I started with an answer and then saw what @PM2Ring noticed, so the error I thought I saw wasn't.  I've deleted the answer and replaced it with another.  But definitely - do not use the same name for a function and a variable.

Comment: As others have said, we need to see the full error message (starting from the line `Traceback (most recent call last):`) so that we can tell which line in your code triggers the error. It would also be helpful to see the code for your `getPointEntity` & `get_itarget` methods, and some info on the structure of `self.player`.

Comment: `self.player.target` is `None`, so it's not a callable method or function. What's the definition of `self.player`? Is `self.player.target` supposed to refer to the method defined as `target` in your first code block?

Answer (score 1):

Inside the `LivingEntity` class you have a method called `target`, and the syntax used by code within the `LivingEntity` class to refer to that `LivingEntity.target` method is `self.target`. But inside the `LivingEntity.set_target` method you *overwrite* `self.target` with the `self.target = target` assignment.

After that assignment, the next time you call the `target` method Python tries to make the call using whatever `set_target` has set `self.target` to, instead of calling the `LivingEntity.target` method that you expect it to use.

So you got that error message because you told `set_target` to set `self.target` to `None`.

Answer (score 1):

As PM 2Ring pointed out, `set_target` overwrites the `LivingEntity.target` field with whatever it gets.  But the problem starts even before that:  the `__init__` method destroys the `target` method before anyone gets a chance to call it.

Here's a stripped-down example of what's happening:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3


class InitDestroysMethod(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.target = None
        return

    def target(self):
        return "This is the InitDestroysMethod.target method."


def main():
    print("Class with __init__ and target method:")
    print("InitDestroysMethod.target:  ", end="")
    print(InitDestroysMethod.target)
    print("InitDestroysMethod.target():  ", end="")
    print(InitDestroysMethod.target(None))  # Bogus "self" argument.
    print()
    print("Instance with __init__ and target method:")
    print("InitDestroysMethod().target:  ", end="")
    print(InitDestroysMethod().target)
    print("InitDestroysMethod().target():  ", end="")
    print(InitDestroysMethod().target())
    return


if "__main__" == __name__:
    main()
```

Below is the output of this program:

```
Class with __init__ and target method:
InitDestroysMethod.target:  <function target at 0x1266490>
InitDestroysMethod.target():  This is the InitDestroysMethod.target method.

Instance with __init__ and target method:
InitDestroysMethod().target:  None
InitDestroysMethod().target():  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./init_vs_method.py", line 30, in <module>
    main()
  File "./init_vs_method.py", line 25, in main
    print(InitDestroysMethod().target())
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

As you can see, the uninstantiated class *does* have a `target` method (technically just a function --- when an object is instantiated, *it* will have a bound method with the `self` parameter bound to the object).  It can be called like any other function, as long as you provide an argument for the `self` parameter.  (That trick only works in this case because `target` doesn't actually *use* its `self` parameter, but it lets me prove that there's a callable function named `target`.)

But an *instance* of the class has already suffered the effects of `__init__`.  In this case, `__init__` sets the value of `target` in the instance dictionary to `None`.  The old value of `target` was a bound method, but by the time you get a reference to the newly-created and initialized object, that old value has long since been discarded.

When you use a field like `some_instance.target`, the search for an entity named "target" starts in the instance dictionary.  That dictionary does indeed have a key named "target".  That the *class* has a function also named "target" makes no difference --- the name has already been found, and its value (`None`) gets used.

Then you try to call that `None` value as if it were a function or a method, and you get a `TypeError`.

Comment: Well spotted, Kevin! I don't know how I missed that `self.target = None` line... maybe my brain was a bit tired after spending so much time waiting for Anagkai to post the necessary details. :)